# How do I show only the first letters of a string?

Tags: java, string, substring, joptionpane

I'm prompting the user to enter their first and last name but I can't figure out how to show just their first and last initials

```
import javax.swing.*;
//import java.awt.*;

public class Lab2Program2 {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;


    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your first name?");
    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your last name?");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your initials are " + 
                            firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean only the first letter of the name? If not how many letters you want to display?

Comment: with substring? (`substring(0,1)`)

Comment: Please try something (I recommend using [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))), then share your code with specific questions.

Comment: If its first letter you need then use, `public char charAt(int index)` method. To get first letter in first name use `firstName.charAt(0)`

Comment: for example, first name is Corey last name is Osmon. Then to show "C.O."

Comment: The javadoc is intended to be read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: ... or just (" Your initials are ": + "John".charAt(0) + " " + "Doe".charAt(0))

Comment: Note that `showMessageDialog` doesn't work with `char` as a parameter.

Comment: ... but it can be used in String concatenation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a message box like you were doing before, this should work:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
    "Your initials are " + firstName.substring(0, 1) + " " + lastName.substring(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chatAt()` method.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "Your initials are " + firstName.charAt(0) + " " + lastName.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstName.charAt(0)` returns the char value at the 0 index. That is the first letter of your firstName String.